# Configure admob test mode

Tags: android, admob

I've just added an AdMob banner in my test app and I'm afraid it's not in "test mode". I mean, this is my code:

```
adView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_adview);
// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXX")
    .build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I took the device id from logcat and replaced in the "XXX" text. **The problem is**: ads are not showing. I found some guys saying that ads may take a long time to start showing in test mode. I'm pretty much ok with that.

**My question is** : AdMob is showing 2 impressions in the admin panel. How is that possible? The app was not published and I added my device as a test one. I did not changed anything in the admob admin panel to 'enable test mode', should I?

I'm affraid Google will consider this just like I'm cheating.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, test ads started showing up a few hours later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sweat it. Google is not going to crush you for 2 aberrant impressions. Click on it lots and that's another story.